# What is another similar logic that is faster than ismember?

Tags: matlab, random

Continue my research,

I need another similar logic with `ismember` that has execution time faster. 
this part of my code and the matrix.

```
StartPost =

    14    50    30     1    72    44    76    68    63    80    25    41;
    14    50    30     1    61    72    42    46    67    77    81    27;
    35    23     8    54    19    70    48    75    66    79     2    84;
    35    23     8    54    82    72    78    68    19     2    48    66;
    69    24    36    52    63    47     5    18    11    82     1    15;
    69    24    36    52    48    18     1    12    80    63     6    84;
    73    38    50     7     1    33    24    68    29    20    62    84;
    73    38    50     7    26    61    65    32    22    18     2    69]

for h=2:2:8,
    ...
       done=all(ismember(StartPost(h,1:4),StartPost(h-1,1:4)));
    ...
end
```

I checked that code by using Profile viewer. I got that in this part that made my code took time execution slowly.

Anyone has experience about this logic, please share. thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `isequal`? <http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html> I'm not sure it's faster (though it probably is), but it's definitely more readable.

Comment: @beaker `isequal` won't cut it here, because `ismember` also returns true for two rows having the same elements in different order, whereas `isequal` doesn't.

Comment: I do not know whether it is faster, but in principle `isempty(intersect(StartPost(h,1:4),StartPost(h-1,1:4)))` should yield the same results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MATLAB has several [undocumented built-in functions](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) which can help you achieve the same results as other functions, only faster.

In your case, you can use [`ismembc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function/):

```
done = all(ismembc(StartPost(h, 1:4), sort(StartPost(h-1, 1:4)))));
```

Note that `ismembc(A, B)` requires matrix `B` to be sorted and not to contain any NaNs values.

Here's the execution time difference for your example:

```
tic
for h = 2:2:8
   done = all(ismember(StartPost(h, 1:4), StartPost(h-1, 1:4)));
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.029888 seconds.


tic
for h = 2:2:8
   done = all(ismembc(StartPost(h, 1:4), sort(StartPost(h-1, 1:4))));
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.006820 seconds.
```

This is about ~50 times faster.

Comment: Mr... in my old version matlab (R2009a) does not have ismembc. I tried to find by using help, I didn't find it.

Comment: ouh sorry, i can use ismembc.

Comment: ok thanks mr, for your information. but why does it take longer time than ismember when I use it in my full code.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Can you provide the benchmarking results / time measurements?