# Making more efficient Matlab ismember for large matrices: any faster suggestion than logical indexing?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following routine in Matlab calling several times  `ismember` within a loop.

```
clear
rng default
%%%% Parameters
XZsup=[1 2; 2 2; 3 2; 1 5; 2 5 ; 3 5];
N=100:100:2000; 

%%%% Allocate space
P1=zeros(size(XZsup,1),size(N,2));
P2=zeros(size(XZsup,1),size(N,2));
time=zeros(size(N,2),1);

for l=1:size(N,2)
    n=N(l);
    %%%% 1) Generate data
    X=unidrnd(3,n,1); %nx1
    XZmu=[unidrnd(3,n^2,1) unidrnd(5,n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1)]; %n^2x5
    %%%% 2) Using ismember, compare each row in XZsup with XZmu and X and fill P1 and P2
    tic
    for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
        num=ismember(XZmu, [XZsup(h,:) 1 1 0], 'rows'); 
        den=ismember(XZmu(:,1:2), XZsup(h,:), 'rows');  
        P1(h,l)=sum(num)/ sum(den);      

        num=ismember(XZmu, [XZsup(h,:) 0 0 1], 'rows'); 
        den=ismember(X,XZsup(h,1));
        P2(h,l)=sum(num)/sum(den); 
    end
    time(l)=toc;
end
```

For large values of `N` the code inside the loop is quite slow. Indeed, I get

```
    time =
    0.0373
    0.1583
    0.3651
    0.7003
    1.2631
    2.0064
    2.9665
    4.0512
    5.4177
    7.2097
    8.9078
   11.0968
   13.3023
   16.0414
   19.0199
   22.3131
   26.3962
   30.1553
   34.3927
   37.9660
```

I would like your help to make this code more efficient. This could be one option

```
clear
rng default
%%%% Parameters
XZsup=[1 2; 2 2; 3 2; 1 5; 2 5 ; 3 5];
N=100:100:2000; 

%%%% Allocate space
P3=zeros(size(XZsup,1),size(N,2));
P4=zeros(size(XZsup,1),size(N,2));
time=zeros(size(N,2),1);

for l=1:size(N,2)
    n=N(l);
    %%%% 1) Generate data
    X=unidrnd(3,n,1); %nx1
    XZmu=[unidrnd(3,n^2,1) unidrnd(5,n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1)]; %n^2x5
    %%%% 2) Using ismember, compare each row in XZsup with XZmu and X and fill P3 and P4
    tic
    for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
        num=(sum(XZmu==[XZsup(h,:) 1 1 0], 2)==5); 
        den=(sum(XZmu(:,1:2)==XZsup(h,:),2)==2);  
        P3(h,l)=sum(num)/ sum(den);    

        num=(sum(XZmu==[XZsup(h,:) 0 0 1], 2)==5); 
        den=(X==XZsup(h,1));
        P4(h,l)=sum(num)/sum(den); 
    end
    time(l)=toc;
end
```

and I get

```
time =

    0.0051
    0.0047
    0.0087
    0.0183
    0.0277
    0.0365
    0.0491
    0.0714
    0.0878
    0.1098
    0.1426
    0.1825
    0.2176
    0.2440
    0.2830
    0.3353
    0.3783
    0.4215
    0.4732
    0.5399
```

**Do you have faster suggestions?**

I have read several questions/answers related to this, e.g.,

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714487/is-there-a-function-like-ismember-but-more-efficient): when I type `builtin('_ismemberoneoutput',...,...)`, Matlab tells me `Error using builtin Cannot find builtin function '_ismemberoneoutput'`; I have tried also with `ismembc` but it does not have the `rows` option.
- [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/173926-can-i-speed-up-an-ismember-operation) but it does not seem to be appropriate for my case

Comment: https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219298/what-is-another-similar-logic-that-is-faster-than-ismember  I used this one in the past, by sorting my inputs.

Comment: Thank you @AnderBiguri. I haven't understood very well how to use sorting with `ismembc` and also how to compare rows with `ismembc`. If you have time, can you write down an answer considering my specific example? Thanks

Comment: You do not need to use `ismember` at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ismember` is expensive. 
So, we can save time by using it as few times as possible.

I made a function to compare OP's method and my way. 
Since I already know from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49759064/3839249) that purely storing large matrices is also slow, I'm trying to avoid it this time.

```
function [P1,P2] = testf(X,XZmu,XZsup, K)

P1=zeros(size(XZsup,1),1);
P2=zeros(size(XZsup,1),1);
switch K
    case 1
        for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
            num=ismember(XZmu, [XZsup(h,:) 1 1 0], 'rows'); 
            den=ismember(XZmu(:,1:2), XZsup(h,:), 'rows');  
            P1(h)=sum(num)/ sum(den);

            num=ismember(XZmu, [XZsup(h,:) 0 0 1], 'rows'); 
            den=ismember(X,XZsup(h,1));
            P2(h)=sum(num)/sum(den); 
        end
    case 2
        for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
            den = ismember(XZmu(:,1:2), XZsup(h,:), 'rows');
            tempNum = (XZmu(:,3)==1) & (XZmu(:,4)==1) & (XZmu(:,5)==0);
            num = tempNum & den;
            P1(h) = sum(num)/sum(den);

            tempNum2 = (XZmu(:,3)==0) & (XZmu(:,4)==0) & (XZmu(:,5)==1);
            num2 = tempNum2 & den;
            den2 = X==XZsup(h,1);
            P2(h) = sum(num2)/sum(den2);
        end
end
end
```

Test code: 
Again I prefer to use `timeit` multiple times.

```
rng default
XZsup=[1 2; 2 2; 3 2; 1 5; 2 5 ; 3 5];
N=[10:20:100-1, 100:200:1000-1, 1000:1000:2000];
Ntrial = 5; % even timeit has variation, so make multiple trials
time=zeros(size(N,2),2);
tempT(Ntrial,2) = 0;

for l=1:size(N,2)
    n=N(l);
    %%%% 1) Generate data
    X=unidrnd(3,n,1); %nx1
    XZmu=[unidrnd(3,n^2,1) unidrnd(5,n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1) randi([0 1],n^2,1)]; %n^2x5
    %%%% 2) Using ismember, compare each row in XZsup with XZmu and X and fill P1 and P2
    for nn = 1:Ntrial
        tempT(nn,:) = [timeit(@() testf(X, XZmu,XZsup, 1), 2), ....
            timeit(@() testf(X, XZmu,XZsup, 2), 2)];
    end
    time(l,:)=mean(tempT,1);
end
plot(N, time(:,1), '--', N, time(:,2), '-')
```

Result: time comparison plot

(I intended to run up to `N=3000` but it's too slow.... see my notes in the end)

[image: time comparison]

Run on Matlab R2015b, Core i7.

---

Side note: your code is very suitable with `parfor`.

I changed the `for` loop over `XZsup` to a `parfor`, and this is the result, compared to case 2.

[image: time comparison with parfor]

Run on Matlab R2018a, on a 8-vCPU system.

For large matrices like 300x300, `parfor` has advantage over `for`. 
For smaller matrices, my speculation is it takes more time to communicate to workers.

Your mileage may vary.

---

Side note 2: This method has more restriction on data, and surprisingly it does NOT work any faster....

```
    case 3
        tempNumCol1 = XZmu(:,3)==1;
        tempNumCol2 = XZmu(:,4)==1;
        tempNumCol3 = XZmu(:,5)==1;
        tempNum = (tempNumCol1) & (tempNumCol2) & (~tempNumCol3);
        tempNum2 = (~tempNumCol1) & (~tempNumCol2) & (tempNumCol3);
        for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
            den = ismember(XZmu(:,1:2), XZsup(h,:), 'rows');
            num = tempNum & den;
            P1(h) = sum(num)/sum(den);

            num2 = tempNum2 & den;
            den2 = X==XZsup(h,1);
            P2(h) = sum(num2)/sum(den2);
        end
```

Comparison between my two methods:

[image: time comparison 2]

---

EDIT: Why not getting rid of `ismember` altogether....

```
    case 3
        tempNum = (XZmu(:,3)==1) & (XZmu(:,4)==1) & (XZmu(:,5)==0);
        tempNum2 = (XZmu(:,3)==0) & (XZmu(:,4)==0) & (XZmu(:,5)==1);
        for h=1:size(XZsup,1)
            tempDen1 = XZmu(:,1)==XZsup(h,1);
            tempDen2 = XZmu(:,2)==XZsup(h,2);
            den = tempDen1&tempDen2;

            num = tempNum & den;
            P1(h) = sum(num)/sum(den);

            num2 = tempNum2 & den;
            den2 = X==XZsup(h,1);
            P2(h) = sum(num2)/sum(den2);
        end
```

[image: time comparison with no ismember]

It's already faster than generating random numebers on my machine.

[image: profiler]