# Making faster a Matlab code involving loop over big dimensions

Tags: matlab

I have this piece of Matlab code that I want to make more efficient if possible. In particular, I want to speed up the two bits (called `BIT 1` and `BIT 2`) - inside the loop over `n` -  which may uselessly take a lot of time for `n_m` and `n_w` large

```
clear
N=[3 4; 100 200; 300 400; 2000 2000; 100000 100000];
output1=cell(size(N,1),1);
output2=cell(size(N,1),1);
for n=1:size(N,1)
    n_m=N(n,1);
    n_w=N(n,2);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
    %BIT 1
    temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
    for i=1:n_m
        temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
    end
    output1{n}=temp(:).'; %1x(n_m*(n_w+1))
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %BIT 2
    temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
    for j=1:n_w
        temp(:,j)=[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m n_m*n_w+n_m+j].';
    end
    output2{n}=temp(:).'; %1x(n_w*(n_m+1))
end
```

**Do you have faster suggestions?**

---

A brief explanation on BIT 1: for a given `n_m` and `n_w`, BIT 1 creates a row vector of dimension `1x(n_m*(n_w+1))` which can be splitted in `n_m` sub-rows each with dimension `1x(n_w+1)`. Sub-row `i` contains the integers `(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i)`.

A brief explanation on BIT 2: for a given `n_m` and `n_w`, BIT 2 creates a row vector of dimension `1x(n_w*(n_m+1))` which can be splitted in `n_w` sub-rows each with dimension `1x(n_m+1)`. Sub-row `j` contains the integers `[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m, n_m*n_w+n_m+j]`.

---

Here I compare the loop version with the `reshape` option: `reshape` does not help.

```
clear
N=3 5; 100 200; 300 400; 2000 2000; 5000 5000; 10000 10000; 20000 20000];
output1=cell(size(N,1),1);
output2=cell(size(N,1),1);
output3=cell(size(N,1),1); %alternative of output1 with reshape
output4=cell(size(N,1),1); %alternative of output2 with reshape
time=zeros(size(N,1),4);
for n=1:size(N,1)
    n_m=N(n,1);
    n_w=N(n,2);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    %BIT 1 with loop  
    tic
    temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
    for i=1:n_m
        temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
    end
    output1{n}=temp(:).'; 
    time(n,1)=toc;
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    %BIT 1 with reshape
    tic
    tempor=reshape(1:1:n_m*(n_w+1), n_m, n_w+1);
    temp1=tempor.'; 
    output3{n}=temp1(:).';
    time(n,3)=toc;
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %BIT 2 with loop
    tic
    temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
    for j=1:n_w
        temp(:,j)=[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m n_m*n_w+n_m+j].';
    end
    output2{n}=temp(:).'; 
    time(n,2)=toc;
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    %BIT 2 with reshape   
    tic
    temp1=tempor(:,1:end-1);
    temp2=n_m*n_w+n_m+1:n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w;
    temp=[temp1; temp2];
    output4{n}=temp(:).';
    time(n,4)=toc;
end
```

and I get

```
time=
0.0003    0.0006    0.0001    0.0001
0.0005    0.0005    0.0003    0.0002
0.0021    0.0011    0.0029    0.0006
0.0159    0.0189    0.0230    0.0189
0.0915    0.1068    0.1503    0.1260
0.3015    0.3757    0.6035    0.5211
1.1501    1.3801    2.4459    2.0828
```

(Third and Fourth columns slower, I have tried to go over 20000 but `reshape` runs forever)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly these vectors you create, but I have the feeling that this is about indices into a matrix. Vectorizing this probably needs `ndgrid` or `meshgrid`, and `sub2ind`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. I don't know about `ngrid` and `sub2ind`. In the question I have added a section where I show that `reshape` does worse than looping. If you have time, could you provide an answer?

Comment: `reshape` takes zero time, it is the permute of the matrix that takes time, it needs to copy the data. Loops are not necessarily slow in recent versions of MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. Indeed, loops are fine, I am just wondering whether there is something faster that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `repmat` which is better than `for` loops *for smaller matrices*

```
function testf(k, N)


n_m=N(1);
n_w=N(2);

switch k
    case 1
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
        %BIT 1
        tempA = ones(n_w+1,1) + (0:n_w).'*n_m;
        tempB = repmat( 0:(n_m-1), n_w+1, 1);
        tempC = tempB(:) + repmat(tempA, n_m, 1);
        output1=tempC(:).'; %1x(n_m*(n_w+1))
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %BIT 2
        tempC = zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
        tempA = repmat((1:n_m).', 1,n_w);
        tempB = repmat( 0:(n_w-1), n_m, 1)*(n_m);
        tempC(1:end-1, :) = tempA + tempB;
        tempC(end, :) = (1:n_w) + (n_w+1)*n_m;
        output2=tempC(:).'; %1x(n_w*(n_m+1))
    case 2
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
        %BIT 1
        temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
        for i=1:n_m
            temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
        end
        output1=temp(:).'; %1x(n_m*(n_w+1))
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %BIT 2
        temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
        for j=1:n_w
            temp(:,j)=[(j-1)*n_m+1:j*n_m n_m*n_w+n_m+j].';
        end
        output2=temp(:).'; %1x(n_w*(n_m+1))
end

end
```

test code

```
figure
N = [100,150; 150,180; 200,250; 250,300; 300,350; 400,500; 450, 550];
T = zeros(size(N,1),size(N,2),10);
for mm = 1:10
    for nn = 1:size(N,1)
        T(nn,:,mm) = [timeit(@() testf(1, N(nn,:))), timeit(@() testf(2, N(nn,:)))];
    end
end
T = mean(T,3);
plot(T)
```

[image: time plot]

running on Matlab R2015b

---

EDIT: I noticed that even `timeit` cannot measure accurate run time. 
So I added a `for` loop to run `timeit` several times.

EDIT: Replies to comments.

> Interesting! Is `ones(n_w+1,1) + (0:n_w).'*n_m` really faster than
>   `(1:n_m:n_m*n_w+1).'`? Also, `repmat( 0:(n_w-1), n_m, 1)*(n_m)` should be
>   slower than `repmat( 0:(n_w-1)*n_m, n_m, 1)` just because there are many
>   more multiplications done.  – Cris Luengo

First question, yes. 
I commented out everything after the first `tempA` in my method, and everything after the first `for` loop in OP's. 
Result is below.

[image: time plot compare a single line of code]

But it's a bit unfair because there is only one line in the `for` loop but my method has three lines. 
Anyway, my original motivation is save time from `for`-ing generation of vectors. 
I can generate a bunch of vectors at one time.

For the multiplications, I have compared the two strategies. Surprisingly, for small matrices like 250x300, there is barely any difference between the two. 
For bigger matrices, the time savings earned from multiplications is far less than the expense of just storing them, so the time plot doesn't really change.

> I really care about N large (above 500) and your answer is suggesting
>   that there is nothing better than looping? – user3285148

It's a challenging part. 
If you really care about *the speed* with a piece of Matlab code.... 
Well here's what I can think of. 
The idea is block-wise is faster than `for` only when the block is small enough. 
So you may chop up the big matrix into smaller chunks, and do the `repmat` style for each small pieces. 
Apparently you will need to stitch all pieces together with a `for` loop, but my bet is on this way would be faster.... 
Also you will have to consider how to *effectively* trim the big matrix to the actual size - say you have a 1234x5678 matrix, and your automated code makes blocks of 100x100.

One example way could be like this

```
    case 3
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
        %BIT 1
        temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
        vec = (1:n_m:(n_m*n_w+1)).';
        for ii=1:n_m
            temp(:,ii) = vec;
            vec = vec + 1;
        end
        output1=temp(:).'; %1x(n_m*(n_w+1))
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %BIT 2
        temp=zeros(n_m+1,n_w);
        vec = (1:n_m).';
        for jj = 1:n_w
            temp(1:end-1,jj) = vec;
            vec = vec + n_m;
        end
        temp(end,:) = n_m*n_w+n_m + (1:n_w);
        output2=temp(:).'; %1x(n_w*(n_m+1))
```

and test code is like this

```
figure
N = [100,150; 150,180; 200,250; 250,300; 300,350; 400,500; 450, 550;
    550,650; 700,800; 800,1000];
T = zeros(size(N,1),3,10);
for mm = 1:10
    for nn = 1:size(N,1)
        T(nn,:,mm) = [timeit(@() testf(1, N(nn,:))), ....
            timeit(@() testf(2, N(nn,:))), ....
            timeit(@() testf(3, N(nn,:)))];
    end
end
T = mean(T,3);
plot(T)
```

then time plot is like this

[image: time plot with case 3]

which shows ~20% of time saving.

Comment: Interesting! Is `ones(n_w+1,1) + (0:n_w).'*n_m` really faster than `(1:n_m:n_m*n_w+1).'`? Also, `repmat( 0:(n_w-1), n_m, 1)*(n_m)` should be slower than `repmat( 0:(n_w-1)*n_m, n_m, 1)` just because there are many more multiplications done.

Comment: Thank you. However, I really care about `N`  large (above `500`) and your answer is suggesting that there is nothing better than looping?

Comment: @Yvon Thanks, very nice! I have another question on speed if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758124/making-more-efficient-matlab-ismember-for-large-matrices-any-faster-suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just a partial answer, while I think about this some more. I can't write this down in a comment...

Note that loops are not necessarily slow. The slowest bit in

> ```
> temp=zeros(n_w+1, n_m);
> for i=1:n_m
>     temp(:,i)=(i:n_m:n_m*n_w+i).'; 
> end
> output1{n}=temp(:).';
> ```

is the indexing. I'm thinking that you might want to write something like this instead:

```
temp = ones(n_w+1, n_m);
temp(:,1) = (1:n_m:n_m*n_w+1).';
temp = cumsum(temp, 2);
output1{n} = temp(:).';
```

I don't have MATLAB here, so can't time it. I have no idea if this is any faster or not.

In BIT 2 you do something similar, but you add `n_m` to the column in every iteration. Thus you need to initialze `temp` to be `n_m` everywhere. `temp(:)=n_m` would be the fastest way to accomplish this, I think.

Comment: Thank you. It is slower than looping unfortunately